# Create an aws_instance with terraform-generated-key-pair

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm using terraform 1.5.7.
I'm creating my environment (instance, with its vpc, subnets, etc.) using Terraform. Since my code needs to be as generic as possible for development environments, i'd like Terraform to create for me the .pem key. I know it's not a good practice, but I'm still learning about the best way to do that.
My main goal is to create the public/private keys, have them stored in my statefile (as mentioned above - not the best practice), and then transfer the relevant parameters to the resource aws_instance, to associate between them.
So far I've made:

```
resource "tls_private_key" "key1" {
  algorithm = "RSA"
  rsa_bits  = 4096
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "key_pair1" {
  key_name   = "myKey"
  public_key = tls_private_key.key1.public_key_openssh
}

resource "aws_instance" "ec2" {
  key_name = tls_private_key.key1.public_key_openssh
}
```

I've also tried with the private_key_openssh, but both times I got the terraform error:
creating EC2 Instance: InvalidParameterValue: Value for parameter ssh-rsa ****** is invalid. Length exceeds the maximum of 255.
│       status code: 400, request id: ***

I would like to:
First - learn what is the proper way to do that, and how should it be done
Second - understand what is my problem here.

Answer (score 0):

`key_name` for the EC2 instance should be the same as `key_name` you specified in `aws_key_pair`. In other words it should be `"myKey"`.  You are passing the entire key again, when you should just be passing the name of the key. Change your code to the following:

```
resource "aws_key_pair" "key_pair1" {
  key_name   = "myKey"
  public_key = tls_private_key.key1.public_key_openssh
}

resource "aws_instance" "ec2" {
  key_name = aws_key_pair.key_pair1.key_name
}
```